# Webpack react-hot-loader not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Below is my webpack.config.js code

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // context: __dirname + "/app",
   entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
     './src/main.jsx'],
    output: {
        path: "./build",
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loaders:  ['react-hot', 'babel'],
          include: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
          query:
            {
              presets:['es2015', 'react']
            },
          plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

And this is script code of my package.son

```
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "webpack",
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --content-base build"
  },
```

And this is my main.js code

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

When I type "npm run dev" , I got this error

```
ERROR in ./src/main.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/testaccount/Documents/React/test-react/src/main.jsx Line 6: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|   <h1>Hello World!</h1>,
|   document.getElementById('example')
| );
 @ multi main
```

And I go to localhost:8080 and nothing show.
Anyone knows what happened?
Why my react-hot-loader is not working?

Comment: 'Make sure react-hot-loader is required before react and react-dom'

Answer (score 6):

I made it work using the solution found [here](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/3183-2). Basically what needs to be done is add `module.hot.accept()` to the script where you render your component to.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MainLayout from './components/MainLayout.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainLayout />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

module.hot.accept(); // <-- this one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [react-hot-boilerplate github](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) and check `.babelrc` file in the github.

Maybe I don't, also check `include`, `query`, `0.0.0.0` in your settings.

Remember, as per your babel version(5 or 6), settings have to be different.

And now react-hot-loader is deprecation. Refer to [react-hot-loader github](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader).

Answer (score 0):

By default react js provides hot reloading feature. 
Still if it's not working:

Try adding `-- --reset-cache` to your run command. 
*for Linux OS

Ref: 
[React js hot reload issue fix for Linux OS](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/8mlelt/hot_reloadinglive_reload_stopped_working_how_do_i/)

[Duplicate issue in github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18899#issuecomment-439612367)