# React hot reload not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, livereload, hot-reload

I am trying to use the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader to enable hot relaod . But the hot reload is not working, when I refresh the page the changes are reflected without builiding but it is not real time. I think when ever I save the changes on jsx it should be reflected  on  html real time right? please correct me if I am wrong

My jsx file

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader'

@observer
class ListingComponent extends Component {
  render() {
  .........
  }
}
export default hot(module)(ListingComponent);

//global function to run from other frameworks
window.WB.react.renderListingComponent = function() {
    render(

        <ListingComponent/>,
        document.getElementById('node')

    );
}
```

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy","transform-class-properties","lodash","react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


// var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/public');
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app');

var config = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        options: {
      // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for Webpack (not Babel itself).
      // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
      // directory for faster rebuilds.
      cacheDirectory: true,
      plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
    },
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

webpack server command

```
npm run dev --watch --hot ----output-public-path=/assets/js/ --inline
```

Comment: Try to clear node cache. Duplicate: [Webpack react-hot-loader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922956/webpack-react-hot-loader-not-working/53351307#53351307)

Comment: Can you try using web pack Hot module loader in webpack.config.js? Replace `plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],` with `plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]`

Comment: try https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1049#issuecomment-451282865

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo 999999 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```