# React server on browser is not auto-refreshing

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx

I was following this [react course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UZrsTqkcW4&t=10377s) from YouTube.
I installed the `create-react-app` successfully and also ran the localhost server successfully on my browser after
`npm start`.
But the problem is that whenever I make a change in the component and save, I have to keep refreshing the browser by myself (browser is not refreshing automatically on save). But the browser of the teacher in that video refreshes automatically.
Please help me. Am I doing something wrong? or what should I do?

Comment: Did you try reinstall create-react-app and start again? Default CRA has hot-reload and maybe since your process install.

Comment: Do you mean that I should delete the "node_modules" folder and install it again?

Comment: make sure you installed the newest version of CRA. and you try to make another project by CRA. if still facing that problem. probably you need to uninstall and install CRA one more time.

Comment: The reinstalling of CRA didn't help but [top answer in this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922956/webpack-react-hot-loader-not-working) helped.

Comment: UPDATE:  so there must be a automatic way where I shouldn't have to add anything to my files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use: `npx create-react-app your-app-name` when creating your apps so you can always have the most updated version. As per the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: I did use those. The browser refreshes allright when I first open the development server and add some changes to the app but when I remove the unnecessary  files like app.css, logo.svh, etc to work from scratch, then the problem occurs.

Comment: check the console tab in your developer tools to see why is not updating. Most likely, you are deleting a file that causes an error you are only seeing in the console

Comment: There's "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."
How can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest you don't delete files unless you know exactly what you are doing. If it works once you open the app and after making changes it reloads automatically, then your original question has been answered and you need to ask another question about another issue. If my answer helped you solve your problem asked in your original question, please go ahead and choose it as the answer. Happy coding

Comment: Well, I was following the video and it shows to delete all files in src folder except index.js. I followed accordingly yet I am facing the problem and the person in the video is not. So, no my question isn't answered and like how am I supposed to work from scratch without deleting those other files in src folder anyways.

Comment: The beauty of React is that it takes away a lot of configuration, so you can focus on developing applications. If you want to start from scratch by trying to understand 100% how React works behind the scenes, it's going to get you frustrated and discouraged. Read the official documentation so you learn properly what you are doing. By simply copying what you see on a video is not going to make you understand. Read the docs... it's my simple suggestion: https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to create your project in a C-drive ( any directory/folder in C drive), where your node packages were installed during the first setup of the node. I had a similar issue when my project was in D-Drive's Directory but switching to C Drive's Directory "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\ReactProjects\frontend\src" fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different reasons why this is happening. Try one of the following solutions:

1 --> Increase the maximum number of allowed watchers in your linux environment. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/troubleshooting#not-enough-watchers) when running webpack inside of a VM like WSL2, as it happens when you execute `npm start`. To do so, issue the following commands in your terminal:

```
sudo nano /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Replace the number you see with `1048576` and save the file. Then type `exit` and relaunch the terminal. Try `npm start` inside of your project folder again.

2 --> If the above didn't work, try setting the `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` environment variable in your linux environment, which will reflect on your react development environment. Normally you would put this in a *.env* file inside of your project folder, but adding the variable to your *.bashrc* file will make it work with any React project you are working on. If you are only experimenting with React for now, I would recommend this solution. This change is unfortunately [necessary](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) when working inside of a virtual machine like WSL. Add the line `export CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` at the end of your .bashrc file. To edit your .bashrc file:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then save the file and exit/relaunch your terminal. Try `npm start` inside of your project folder again. Hopefully this should fix it.